# How to run a method of a class as a cron task in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, cron, laravel-5.1

Look I have a class that looks like this, i want to cache some info every day in a cron job with this method cacheTopFilters in laravel 5.1

```
<?php
namespace namescape/of/the/class;

class FilterTypeCacheService extends BaseService implements IFilterTypeCacheService
{

    private $searchFilterService;
    private $filterCacheHandler;

    function __construct(SearchFilterService $searchFilterService, IFilterTypeCacheHandler $filterCacheHandler){
        $this->searchFilterService = $searchFilterService;
        $this->filterCacheHandler = $filterCacheHandler;
    }

    public function cacheTopFilters($type,$keyValuePair,$limit){
        $filters = $this->searchFilterService->getAllFilters($type,$keyValuePair);
        $this->filterCacheHandler->deleteFiltersBulkFromCache();
        $this->filterCacheHandler->SaveFiltersBulk($filters,$type);
    }

    public function getTopFilters(){
        $topFilters = $this->filterCacheHandler->getCachedTopFilters();
        return $topFilters;
    }
}
```

As they have dependency injection how can i accomplished to called that method on the app/console/kernel on the schedule method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to take a look at Task Scheduling:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling#defining-schedules

In the `App\Console\Kernel` class, inside the `schedule` function, you can schedule anything at all like this:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    doSomething();
})->daily();
```

Assuming you have the scheduler setup (system cron job every minute) you should be all set.

If you have a class you need to instantiate, with dependencies injected, you can always use the global `app()` helper function that Laravel gives you:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    app(\namespace\of\the\class::class)->cacheTopFilters(...);
})->daily();
```

That's assuming that Laravel knows how to handle your dependencies. I see that one of your dependencies is a contract (interface) so I'm assuming you've already bound the concrete instance in the Laravel IoC.

Comment: do i have to import the namespace on the kernel class or im i fine like that?

Comment: can i make instances inside schedule method?

Comment: I don't see any namespaces in your code example. If you need to import, do it at the top sure. Of course you can create instances inside there. You can run any code into the `$schedule->call` block.

Comment: this class that contains the method has some independency injections on his constructor, making a constructor in the kernel class would be dumb?

Comment: @user3163732 maybe it would be better for you to show some examples of what you're trying to run inside the schedule method? update your question.

Comment: there, any idea mate

Comment: @user3163732 yep just updated my answer. `app()` is your ticket to instantiating a class anywhere, and have Laravel handle dependencies for you.